# Prevent caching and stale content with a static web site

Tags: html, caching, http-caching, static-content

I am considering generating .html files for my entire web site as I want my site to be as fast as possible. The files would be generated with dynamic content via a backend service as data updates occur.

**How do I ensure users always see the latest content?** Say I publish a change to my home page, index.html. How do I prevent these files from always coming from the user's cache and ensure new content, if available, is always retrieved and displayed?

Remember, I am using pure HTML.

If there is absolutely no way, I would not be adverse to using .php files containing HTTP cache-related header() calls prior to the content; e.g.:

```
<?php header(...) ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

    etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about those meta tags. Are these heavily reliable and safe?

Comment: It looks like this will prevent caching by browsers but not proxies, since proxies rely on HTTP headers, not HTML contents. I may use .php files with header() calls, and then make the rest of the file completely static.